# "Would have" or "would" in a conditional sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> Athenians loved a good argument…they loved to be entertained…and most
>   of the time you could find both of those things in the courthouse.
>   Athenians ***would have been*** HUGE fans of Judge Judy…or back then
>   it ***would’ve been*** “Judge Judicles”…

([Source](http://philosophizethis.org/socrates-sophists-episode-3-transcript/))

Why "would have + v3" form was used in these sentences? Why not just "would + infinitive". What does these marked phrases mean in these particular sentences?

Comment: This conversation about a previous version of the question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99058/discussion-on-question-by-talha-ozden-would-have-or-would-in-a-conditional-s).